# jQuery conflict causing woocommerce product images not to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this script to hide navigation at a certain point on the homepage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dot-nav").show(); //show div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = jQuery("#hidedn").offset().top;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            jQuery("#dot-nav").hide(100); //reached the desired point -- hide div
        }
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv) { //hide div
            jQuery("#dot-nav").show(100);
        }
    });
});
```

However it's causing woocommerce product images to not load. I don't need the script on the woocommerce pages so before I attempt to mess with functions.php to enqueue it only on the homepage does anyone know how I can solve this? I'm little more than a jQuery novice so I do apologise if you need more context etc!

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised, because you cannot get the offset of hidden element, or element that does not exist.

> jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element.

What you need to do is to check if element exists:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var dotNav = jQuery("#dot-nav");
    var theDiv = jQuery("#hidedn:visible");
    if( dotNav.length>0 && theDiv.length>0 ) {
        dotNav.show(); //show div initially
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            var topOfOthDiv = theDiv.offset().top;
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
                dotNav.hide(100); //reached the desired point -- hide div
            }
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv) {
                dotNav.show(100);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Please note: you need to check the offset **inside** the window scroll event.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Really elegant solution.